# Modularity in igraph: before and after October 2021

Tags: version, igraph, modularity

In igraph when I cluster the karate network (`kar`) with, say, `cluster_fast_greedy`, to give `karfg`, using `modularity(karfg)` gives 0.4345215. The deprecated option of including membership
`modularity(kar, membership(karfg))` gives 0.399096. Is there an explanation for this discrepancy? (It is not fastgreedy specific, other community detection methods also give a discrepancy).

```
library(igraph)
library(igraphdata)
data(karate)
kar <- karate
karfg<-cluster_fast_greedy(karate)

modularity(kar, membership(karfg))
0.3990796
modularity(karfg)
0.4345215
```

Comment: I do not think that this behaviour has changes recently. You say "before and after October 2021". Can you please be specific and state in which version you get a different result than what you show here?

Comment: Also: using the `modularity` function is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the `modularity` function does not use edge weights by default, while most community detection functions do. The graph you are working with has a `weight` edge attribute, which will be used by `cluster_fast_greedy()` unless you explicitly prevent that.

This is how you can use it in `modularity` as well:

```
modularity(karate, membership(karfg), weights=E(karate)$weight)
```

```
0.4345215
```

---

Note that not all of igraph's community detection functions make use of weights, and those that do may not use it in the same way. Thus, when you call `modularity` explicitly, and separately from the community detection function, be careful to specify weights that match with how the community detection was done.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply and for the explanation! That makes very much sense.